# Firebase rules as alternative to Firebase Custom Tokens

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have added Firebase auth to an existing website. Users can follow, favorite, etc. It's an independent JavaScript layer on top of the old website.

Now I would like to give certain users editing privileges, but I want to do this with Firebase rules, so that all users can continue to log in with Firebase auth (not through our server using JWTs).

I propose to add a child node, "editor" (with children specifying detailed permissions), to the user's record under /users and check for the existence of that child. If it exists, authorized "editor" users will see forms and buttons allowing them to add/edit content.

I would like to prevent unauthorized users knowing about that stuff, even though the Firebase location where the content is posted will be secured by a Node.js program that will check the editor's permissions to determine the final disposition of the added/edited content. So it wouldn't be too easy for an unauthorized user to actually mess with our content.

How can I protect the script that sets up the editing interface? Could the script itself, or essential parts of it, be stored in the real-time database, protected by rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Control Access with Custom Claims and Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)

Then in your database rules:

> ```
> {
>   "rules": {
>     "adminContent": {
>       ".read": "auth.token.admin === true",
>       ".write": "auth.token.admin === true",
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Installing a node.js server (for the admin SDK) is actually easy. Then a script like below can be used to dish out the custom claim based on uid.

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require("./blahblahblah-firebase-adminsdk-blahblahblah.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://blahblahblah.firebaseio.com"
});

admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims("asdfblahblahblahhlkjh", {admin: true}).then(() => {
    console.log("Custom Claim Added to UID. You can stop this app now.");
});
```

Comment: This would mean using JWTs and logging in through our server. That's what I want to avoid.

Comment: No this creates a custom claim in the `firebase.auth` subsystem. In other words once you set the custom claim on the uid you can then use security rules. This is all done firebase side (server/cloud side). You will not need to create any JWT's or any server at all (except to dish out the initial claim to the `.auth` uid.

Comment: This looks good, way better that my hacky idea. I can set the custom claim when I set up an editor. I wanted to hide the editor scripts but it's more of an aesthetic preference than a security requirement. Thanks @Ron!